# Using entity framework to detect changes in related table and action appropriate inserts and deletes

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

Lets say i have a `Person` table, a `Role` table with a trel table `PersonRoles` linking them as many to many.

I create a new person and assign them to 2 roles (role 1, role 3).

I then want to edit this person; so i retrieve their data and bind their roles to a checkboxes. I change the values (Deselect role 1 and select role 2 instead) I then post this data back through a viewmodel.

Can i then get Entity Framework to update these roles for me, as in delete the entry in `PersonRoles` to role 1 and then add a new entry as role 2? Or do i have to do the logic for this myself?

Something like ** **this** ** i was hopeing but doesn't work obviously.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, PersonViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var person= GetPerson(id);
            person.Name= model.Name;
            person.Age = model.Age;

           ICollection<Roles> personroles = new Collection<Roles>();
            foreach (string rId in model.Roles)
            {
                personroles.Add(this.RoleRepository.Single(r => r.Id.ToString() == rId));
            }

            **person.Roles = personroles;**

            this.PersonRepository.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToIndex(personId);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Cheers,
Kohan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The devil is in the details, and you don't give any, but generally, yes, the EF can do this.

The best approach is to make `PersonRoles` have only two columns: The FKs to `Person` and `Role`, with cascading deletes on both, and make the PK a compound key on both. If you have no other columns, the EF will subsume this table into a many to many relationship which will behave the way you're expecting.

**Update:** Since you've now added source, let's fix it (untested; this is off the top of my head):

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var person= GetPerson(id);
        person.Name= model.Name;
        person.Age = model.Age;

        var rolesToAdd = model.Roles.Where(mr => !person.Roles.Any(pr => pr.Id == mr);
        var rolesToRemove = person.Roles.Where(pr => !model.Roles.Any(mr => pr.Id == mr);

        foreach (string rId in rolesToAdd)
        {
            person.Roles.Add(this.RoleRepository.Single(r => r.Id.ToString() == rId));
        }
        foreach (string rrId in rolesToRemove)
        {
            var remove = person.Roles.Where(r => r.Id == rrId).Single();
            person.Roles.Remove(remove);
        }

        this.PersonRepository.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToIndex(personId);
    }
```

Comment: I have added some code, this is what i was hopeing to do, but am i required to do more than this to get it working? My table structure is implemented as you described.

Comment: Ahh okay, that's what I meant by adding my own logic. I was hopeing that by trying to set person.Roles to a new IEnumerable of Roles, it would do the comparisons itself and see what needed added and removing and then actioning those inserts itself. If it means as you have shown there that i have to do these checks myself, that is the route i shall take. Many thanks again. (You always seem to end up answering my questions, hehe).